# is there away to track slider swiping using GTM?

Tags: slider, google-tag-manager, slick.js

I am looking for a methodology to track when user swipe the slider to the right or to the left only! not anything else, only swiping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with a custom event.  This is how to capture the swipe event with the direction. First, push a custom event to the dataLayer when a slider swipe event is triggered:

```
<script>
    $('#slider').on('swipe', function (event, slick, direction) {
        dataLayer.push({"event": "sliderSwipe", "swipeDirection": direction});
    });
</script>
```

In GTM, create a custom trigger:

```
Trigger name: Slider Swipe
Trigger type: Custom Event
Event name: sliderSwipe
Trigger fires on: All custom events
```

Create a user-defined variable:

```
Variable name: Swipe Direction
Variable type: Data Layer Variable
Data layer variable name: swipeDirection
```

Create a new tag:

```
Tag type: Google Analytics: Universal Analytics
Category: Slider
Action: Swipe
Label: {{Swipe Direction}}
Trigger:  Slider Swipe
```

Comment: what should i select to fire the trigger?

Comment: Does the JavaScript only work with slick.js? I use the owl-carousel and put the code, the trigger, the variable and the tag as mentioned, but the trigger is not triggering. Thanks for the help!